# Amazon Side Bar Menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

Does anybody knows how to resolve the issue in Amazon plugin when I try to put it on my site and put on the third level a checkbox or click somewhere on the div, the level div fades out. how to make the div stay?

This is the plugin

[Amazon Plugin](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1463/Amazon-Side-Bar-Menu-with-jquery)

```
    <nav id="mysidebarmenu" class="amazonmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Folder 0</a>
    <div>
        <p>Browse our spring collection of useful webmaster tools and resources! Everything from JavaScript, CSS to PHP are covered!</p>

      <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.javacriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/">CSS Library</a>
      <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/tools">Webmaster Tools</a>
            <div>
                <p><h3><a href="http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/imageoptimizer/">Image Optimizer</a></h3>
                Use this tool to easily optimize regular gifs, animated gifs, jpgs, and pngs, so they load as fast as possible. 
                </p>

                <p><h3><a href="http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/">FavIcon Generator</a></h3>
                Generate a favicon using any regular image with this tool. 
                </p>

                <p><h3><a href="http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/animatedgif/">Animated Gif Generator</a></h3>
                Animated Gif Generator lets you easily create an animated gif by uploading a series of still images! 
                </p>

            </div>

      <li><a href="http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/">PHP For the Absolute Beginner</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Folder 1</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 1.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 1.3</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Item 1.3.1</li>
            <li>Sub Item 1.3.2</li>
            <li>Sub Item 1.3.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 1.3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Folder 2</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 2.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 2.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 2.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 2.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 2.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/">Sub Item 2.1</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/style/">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
jQuery(function(){
amazonmenu.init({
    menuid: 'mysidebarmenu'
})
})
```

Comment: Please http://jsfiddle.net/ a working example and fix indentation, thanks ;)

Comment: I already indicate the working plugin, this is the link

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1463/Amazon-Side-Bar-Menu-with-jquery

Comment: The [demo](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/1463/Amazon-Side-Bar-Menu-with-jquery) doesnt show it working? maybe its a problem with the plugin

Comment: Why would you want to rely on a javascript library to do this when you could achieve much better results with CSS? http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/umEgv